# Не найден словарь ресурсов

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Почему возникает такая ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом проект нормально собирается, но при запуске падает с ошибкой...

Comment: Видимо поиск идет из того места, где находится скомпилированный исходник, т.е. в папки bin/debug. Попробуйте заменить строку на ../Style/Style.xaml

Comment: да! действительно помогло, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Trymount оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо поиск идет из того места, где находится скомпилированный исходник, т.е. в папки bin/debug. Попробуйте заменить строку на ../Style/Style.xaml